# How do you manually set switches when you are compiling Stockfish in Visual Studio?

Tags: engines, stockfish

How do you manually set switches when you are compiling Stockfish in Visual Studio?

In the type.h file it saids:

> When Makefile is not used (e.g. with Microsoft Visual Studio) some switches
>   need to be set manually:
>
> -DNDEBUG      | Disable debugging mode. Always use this for release.
>
> -DNO_PREFETCH | Disable use of prefetch asm-instruction. You may need this to
>                 | run on some very old machines.
>
> DUSE_POPCNT  | Add runtime support for use of popcnt asm-instruction. Works
>                | only in 64-bit mode and requires hardware with popcnt support.
>
> -DUSE_PEXT    | Add runtime support for use of pext asm-instruction. Works
>                 | only in 64-bit mode and requires hardware with pext support.

I just want to where where/how do you put these "commands"?

Comment: This is just off-topic.

Comment: sorry, do you know where i should move the thread to?

Comment: also im just wondering, how is this off topic? i just want to know so i can prevent this from happening again in the future.

Comment: Compiling C++ source code shouldn't be on-topic but I could be wrong. Let's leave the community to decide.

Answer (score 1):

This question should be in programming.

These can be put in a top h file, the best being stdafx.h.  Just include "#define DNDEBUG",

They can be added to the command line/compiler commands.  Under VS6, Project->Settings (Alt+f7), there is a box to add project settings under the c/c++ tab.

Comment: I can't seem to find stdafx.h. Do you know where it is? Also do you know what the name of the box that I can add project settings to?

Comment: Stdafx.h is automatically created when you make a new project, so that wouldn't be included in the download, my error.  (When I began, I always had the error that the compiler couldn't find stdafx.h and just created a dummy workspace and added code as a project.) I have the debug option in the "Project Options" box, so I assume that would be correct.